# Algorithm to determine if two polygons intersect

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry

I'm working on an algorithm which should check if two polygons, described by their vertex coordinates, are: one inside the other, are intersecting or are separated

image below describe this three cases: [image: example]

i'm thinking about how to do it but i'm not having any idea. Any suggestion?

**solved:**
i solved using Shamos-Hoey Algorithm and Winding Number method

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20694/mathematical-programming-formulation-of-triangle-intersection/20717#20717 (and replace point inside triangle with point inside polygon test, shoot an infinite ray from the point and count the intersections (odd->inside, even->outside)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272179/a-simple-algorithm-for-polygon-intersection and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiler–Atherton_clipping_algorithm.

Comment: Look up *collision detection*.

Comment: If you managed to solve this, it may be better to include that solution as an answer. This is a highly viewed question, so it seems to be of interest to other users.